# mvc view select dropdown ui improvement

Tags: html, asp.net-core-mvc

so i currently have this as my select in mvc view html

```
<select style="width:88%" asp-for="Account.CustomerID" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.ViewID,"CustomerID","CustomerID"))" required></select>
```

this works by showing all the customer ids in a dropdown, but if there are over 1000 customer ids in my model then the drop down will become too big.

so i want to change it so that when a user starts typing it will show only the the numbers matching the inputs,

like if my model has 100,111,112,200,201,202

a user starts typing 1 only 100,101, and 102 will show, then if they type another 1 only 111 and 112 will show

Comment: Hi @Andrew Lin, I think you could try AutoComplete plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a whole working demo you could follow:

Model:

```
public class Account
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
}
public class Test
{
    public Account Account { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model Test
<input type="text" asp-for="Account.CustomerID" />
@section Scripts{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#Account_CustomerID").autocomplete({
                source: '/Home/Test'
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Test()
    {
        var name = HttpContext.Request.Query["term"].ToString();
        var model = new List<Account>()   //you can get data from the database
        {
           new Account(){CustomerID=101},
           new Account(){CustomerID=102},
           new Account(){CustomerID=103},
           new Account(){CustomerID=110},
           new Account(){CustomerID=111},
           new Account(){CustomerID=112},
           new Account(){CustomerID=113},
        };

        //autocomplete accept string array in frontend
        var customerID = model.Where(c => c.CustomerID.ToString().Contains(name))
                            .Select(c => c.CustomerID.ToString()).ToList();
        return Ok(customerID);
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]